# How to assign combobox values with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, combobox

Imagine that you have an array like this:

```
myArray[0] = 1,2,3
myArray[1] = 2,3,5
myArray[2] = 1,4,5
```

Where (1,2,3),(2,3,5),(1,4,5) are combobox values.

eg. When myArray[0]:

```
<select name="somename" id="someid">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

eg. When myArray[1]:

```
<select name="somename" id="someid">
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="3">three</option>
<option value="5">five</option>
</select>
```

Now, the point is assign one of this `myArray[]` values to the comboboxes? Is it possible?
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No jQuery, assuming you have the "Select" object already:

```
var s = document.getElementById('someid');
var words = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray[0].length; i++){
   var t = document.createElement("option")
   t.value = myArray[0][i];
   t.textContent = words[myArray[0][i]-1];
   s.appendChild(t)
}
```

(**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gfSbF/2/)**)

Otherwise, add:

```
var s = document.createElement("select");
s.id = 'someid';
s.name = 'somename';
var words = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray[0].length; i++){
   var t = document.createElement("option")
   t.value = myArray[0][i];
   t.textContent = words[myArray[0][i]-1];
   s.appendChild(t)
}
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

I prefer manual DOM manipulation (`.textContent`) over `innerHTML`, because `innerHTML` forces the browser to re-parse the entire DOM, each time it is used, since the browser can't possibly predict the structure of the added HTML. This makes DOM manipulation render faster than when using `innerHTML`

Comment: @skdnewbie: In that case, the first section of code in my answer should do it, not?

Comment: no no no I think you misunderstood me. When it is `myArray[1]` then there is this optons: `<option value="2">two</option>``<option value="3">three</option>``<option value="5">five</option>`

Comment: Bu if `myArray[2`], then there is this options `<option value="1">xpto</option><option value="4">xpto</option><option value="5">xpto</option>`

Answer (score 2):

Of course. You can loop the elements in the array and then build your html from that.

```
var html = '';

for(var i = 0; i < myArray[0].length; i++){
   html += '<option value="' + myArray[0][i] + '">' + myArray[0][i] + '</option>';
}

document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML = html;
```

NOTE: This is a very simple sample to demonstrate the logic. You will also of course need a way to convert your number to a text value (i.e. convert 1 to "one") if you really need that functionality.

If this isn't what you want, then try to explain your question better. It is not clear if you want to use a specific index of `myArray` for create one select. Or if you want to populate multiple select lists (which already exist) with the corresponding array values. If the latter, then you should be more clear about what "someid" really is so we can identify each select list correctly.

Comment: dont worry with one/two/etc are not related to 1,2,3,etc :)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your array and create the appropriate DOM elements. Here is an example, you will need to add a lookup array of numeric values to words:

```
numwords = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"];
myArray = [];
myArray[0] = [1,2,3];
myArray[1] = [2,3,5];
myArray[2] = [1,4,5];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    var select = document.createElement('select');
    for(var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++){
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = myArray[i][j];
        option.innerHTML = numwords[myArray[i][j] - 1];
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(select);
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/YJj3b/1

Comment: in your live example I see some undifined values, is meant to be ?

Comment: @skdnewbie Yeah I accidentally typed plus instead of minus. Here's a fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/YJj3b/1/